# Bootstrap 4 removes CSS styling for small screens?

Tags: css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I have been out of the web development scene for a number of years and am getting back into it and developing a website using Bootstrap 4.

This maybe a stupid question but I have some CSS styling for checkboxes for some form elements and when reducing the screen size < 768px the styling vanishes...

Is this something fundamental to Bootstrap (although have not had this happen with any other CSS styled elements?) or am I doing something very obviously wrong?

Here are some code segments:

```
.question input {
   position: absolute;
   left: -9999px;
 }

.question label {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 15px 30px 15px 55px;
   border: 3px solid #fff;
   border-radius: 20px;
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #005552;
   white-space: pre-wrap;
   cursor: pointer;
   user-select: none;
   transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
}

.question label::before {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   bottom: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   width: 32px;
   border: 3px solid #fff;
   border-radius: 20px;
   transition: background-color .2s;
}

.question input:checked + label {
   background-color: #ab576c;
 }

 .question input:checked + label::before {
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  <form target="nextQuestion.php" action="post" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <input type="hidden" name="percentage" id="percentage">
        <input type="hidden" name="currentQuestion" id="currentQuestion" value="1">         
        <div class="container-fluid">   
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 my-auto toxic-red-background" align="center">
                    <h6 class="white-text">Your Progress Through Our Questionnaire: </h6>
                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar-animated bg-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: 5%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 toxic-teal-background questionnaire-left-section question">
                    <h3>Q1: Would you use out website again?</h3>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <input type="hidden" value="Question2">
                    <input id="yes" type="checkbox" class="QuestionnaureInput">
                    <label for="yes" class="QuestionnaireLabel">Yes</label>
                    <input id="no" type="checkbox" class="QuestionnaureInput">
                    <label for="no" class="QuestionnaireLabel">No</label>
                    <input id="maybe" type="checkbox" class="QuestionnaureInput">
                    <label for="maybe" class="QuestionnaireLabel">Maybe</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 clearfix">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2 float-left">Prev</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 float-right">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here are some screen grabs to illustrate what is happening:

[On larger screen - All OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9PeF.png)

[Screen resized to < 768px and styling is removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xaGU.png)

Any suggestions, answers or guidance gratefully received as I am pulling my hair out!!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Where is your html code ?

Comment: Check in the DOM inspector of your developer tools. You should see what's overwriting your styles.

Comment: HTML code is after the CSS code

Comment: @Klooven. I have already checked that. The styles are there in the Dom inspector until the screen becomes < 768px and then those styles simply vanish; there are no other styles that are overwriting them. My media queries only adjust font sizes for screen sizes so there is nothing in there.